# Camunda Can't find scripting engine for 'python': scriptEngine is null

Tags: camunda, camunda-plugin

```
The process could not be started. :
Cannot instantiate process definition Process_03eqpht:3:7ff29d88-51a6-11ec-820b-4e796e7082df: Can't find scripting engine for 'python': scriptEngine is null
```

I have install camunda and running it but when i run new process which has python as script define in it. Camunda throw error for python and groovy script.

I have python already installed in system.

This is camunda workflow:-

[image]

Running of camunda:

[image]

Error:

[image]

Comment: Did you find anything? I face this this with every language I tried JavaScript and Groovy.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a Scripting Engine that can run Phyton.
There is support for Jyton:

> Camunda Platform supports scripting with JSR-223 compatible script engine implementations. Currently we test the integration for Groovy, JavaScript, JRuby and **Jython**. To use a scripting engine it is necessary to add the corresponding jar to the classpath.

See the documentation: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.17/user-guide/process-engine/scripting/

I haven't done that - but here is a discussion on how to use Camunda with Python: https://forum.camunda.io/t/python-integration-with-camunda/8846/2